# Fantasy series where all the forests have been cut down

Tags: story-identification

I think this was from the 1980s, a series of fat books. There is a leader called the Axe or similar, a woman who plants trees, and lots of military stuff. Also some immortals who interfere and torment people, they can fly, and turn out to be aliens. At the end people enter the hidden spacecraft and reclaim their heritage. Maybe Star something? I thought the author was Colleen McCullough but can't find these books in her list of works.

Comment: Sara Douglas's Wayfarer"s books maybe.

Comment: Thank you, it was Sara Douglass's Axis Trilogy -- Battleaxe, Enchanter and Starman. I'm new, how do I show that the question has been answered?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to eshier for suggesting Sara Douglass.

It was Sara Douglass's *[Axis Trilogy](https://goo.gl/PWPr53)* — *Battleaxe*, *Enchanter* and *Starman*.

Comment: Awesome! Can I suggest you maybe add some more details like a plot summary and maybe a cover or two, so other people who find the question can easily see if this is what they were looking for too. As for showing the question was answered, in about 2 days (because this is a self answer) you'll be able to click the little check-mark under your score and accept it.